# Chart.js horizontal bar grid line colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, chart.js, chart.js2

I have started to you the excellent chart.js library in my ASP.Net MVC application.

Firstly, top add-in for charting. I am using version Version: 2.7.2

Now for the main issue that I am currently banging my head on.

First the code.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
 }

<div class="container">
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="60"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/Chart.js"></script>
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "horizontalBar",
        data: {
            labels: ["Totals"],
            datasets: [
                { label: "A", data: [1800], backgroundColor: "rgba(165, 97, 125, 1.0)" },
                { label: "B", data: [1800], backgroundColor: "rgba(239, 195, 77, 1.0)" },
                { label: "C", data: [1800], backgroundColor: "rgba(70, 89, 71, 1.0)" },
                { label: "D", data: [900], backgroundColor: "rgba(82, 103, 161, 1.0)" },
                { label: "E", data: [2400], backgroundColor: "rgba(161, 132, 82, 1.0)" },
                { label: "F", data: [1300], backgroundColor: "rgba(82, 160, 161, 1.0)" }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [
                    {
                        barThickness: 13,
                        ticks: {
                            min: 0,
                            max: 11000,
                            stepSize: 3000,
                            display: true,
                            beginAtZero: false,
                            fontSize: 9,
                            color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0)",
                            callback: function (value, index, values) {
                                var q = value / 100;
                                return q + 'k';
                            }
                        },
                        gridlines: {
                            display: false,
                        },
                        stacked: true
                    }
                ],
                yAxes: [{
                    gridlines: {
                        color: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)'
                    },
                    display: true,
                    stacked: true
                }]
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Simple self-contained example, that does produce a stacked horizontal bar.

My issue is that I wish to change the color of the yAxes grid line, the code above shows a color of rgb(241,241,241), not what is defined.

The configuration is how it is described in the documentation.

Can anyone help by showing what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to change the `gridlines` attribute to `gridLines` and it will work as expected !

Below is the working codepen example.

See the Pen [ChartJS Axis color](https://codepen.io/amanboss9/pen/NBWYmj/) by Aman Sharma ([@amanboss9](https://codepen.io/amanboss9)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

Comment: Thank you Aman for your reply. It does work, but maybe I was asking the wrong question. I have played with the CodePen example you provided and this changes the x/y axis color, but not the grid lines color.

Comment: If my understanding is correct ,If you will add color property to the gridLines in xAxes and yAxes, accordingly it add color to the grids. check the updated example in code pen.

Comment: This is so weird, it is working in the example provided, and I also got it working in the first example provided, but it still does not work in my app. Thank you for the reply and I will mark this as completed. Must be the code in my app.

Comment: Found the issue. In my code I had double quote bounding the color definition. Silly me. Changed to single quotes and all working correctly.